# EKCalendarChooser new Calendar

Tags: ios, ios5, eventkit

Is it possible to show the enable adding new calendars in EKCalendarChooser just like the default iPhone Calendar app shows the + in the upper left corner and allows you to define you calendars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been seeking the same ready-to-use solution for almost a day and no luck so far..

The good thing is, however, that you can call

```
[yourEKCalendarChooserInstance setEditing:YES];
```

And It will show you the "Add Calendar" row

But the bad thing is that nothing happens on click/select.
That's all I found out so far

UPDATE:

this code worked for me (test only on simulator so far):

```
EKEventStore *store = [[[EKEventStore alloc] init] autorelease];
EKCalendarChooser *chooser = [[EKCalendarChooser alloc] initWithStyle:EKCalendarChooserSelectionStyleSingle displayStyle:EKCalendarChooserDisplayWritableCalendarsOnly eventStore:store];
[chooser setEditing:YES];
[chooser setShowsDoneButton:YES];
[chooser setShowsCancelButton:YES];
UINavigationController *modalController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:chooser];
[self presentViewController:modalController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

In addition, of course, you will need to provide delegate for done/cancel buttons.

Comment: I don't agree with this message being marked as an answer. It does not provide the solution. In fact the `Done` and `Cancel` buttons do not even appear when the `EKCalendarChooser` is in editing mode. The only way this can be achieved is loading two separate instances of EKCalendarChooser, one for editing and one for selecting

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of trial and errors,
I finally got it:

```
var calendarChooser: EKCalendarChooser!
var navController: UINavigationController!

func setup () {
    calendarChooser =  EKCalendarChooser(
        selectionStyle: EKCalendarChooserSelectionStyleMultiple,
        displayStyle: EKCalendarChooserDisplayAllCalendars,
        entityType: EKEntityTypeEvent,
        eventStore: zeitplanController.cache.eventStore)
    // DON'T DO THE FOLLOWING:
    // calendarChooser.editing = false
    navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: calendarChooser)
    calendarChooser.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Edit, target: self, action: "startEditing")
}

func startEdit () {
    calendarChooser.editing = true
    calendarChooser.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Done, target: self, action: "endEdit") }

func endEdit () {
    calendarChooser.editing = false
    calendarChooser.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Edit, target: self, action: "startEdit")
}
```

This, put in a UIPopoverController shows the standard Calendar Chooser Dialog including editing functionality, like in the original calendar app.

@Apple: please do us the favor and update the documentation, to make our lives easier

Comment: Weird. The EKCalendarChooserDelegate methods are being called, but the selectedCalendars are blank. Looks like you're trying to duplicate in setting up those buttons what the docs say the delegate method does already. Am I missing something?