# Edit button is missing on EKCalendarChooser View

Tags: ios, calendar, edit

Using below code displays the EKCalendarChooser View.But Edit button is missing on that view.

```
  EKEventStore * eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

  EKCalendarChooser *calendarChooser = [[EKCalendarChooser alloc]
                                              initWithSelectionStyle:EKCalendarChooserSelectionStyleMultiple
                                          displayStyle:EKCalendarChooserDisplayAllCalendars
                                          eventStore:eventStore];

 calendarChooser.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
        calendarChooser.delegate = self;
        calendarChooser.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
        [calendarChooser.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
        calendarChooser.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = calendarChooser.editButtonItem;
          [self.navigationController pushViewController:calendarChooser animated:NO];
```

Thanks for help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put the EKCalendarChooser into a UINavigationController
and add the button manually.

see my answer here:

[EKCalendarChooser new Calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9660419/ekcalendarchooser-new-calendar)